# How to get all data in a csv file by scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

By this code I am only getting the last data from this website. As I want to get all of the data but it's not working right. What have I done wrong in this code??

```
import scrapy


class YellowPages(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yp'

    start_urls = [
           "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=agent&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=1",
           ]

    def parse(self, response):
        agent_name = response.xpath("//a[@class='business-name']/span/text()").extract()
        phone_number = response.xpath("//div[@class='phones phone primary']/text()").extract()
        address = response.xpath("//div[@class='street-address']/text()").extract()
        locality = response.xpath("//div[@class='locality']/text()").extract()


        data = zip(agent_name, phone_number, address, locality)

        for item in data:
            info = {
                'page' : response.url,
                'Agent_name': item[0],
                'Phone_number': item[1],
                'address': item[2],
                'locality':item[3],
            }

        yield info
```

I have also done this in setting.py file.

```
FEED_FORMAT="csv"
FEED_URI="yp.csv"
```

The data I am getting on my csv file--

```
page,Agent_name,Phone_number,address,locality
https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=agent&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=1,Pedro Maldonado - State Farm Insurance Agent,(323) 583-1111,1933 E Florence Ave,"Los Angeles, CA 90001"
```

There should be 30 rows with all of the data but I am only getting 1 row and which should be the last row of my preferred data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to indent your last line correctly to be inside of the for-loop and your code will work just as expected. Right now you are calling `yield info` outside of you for-loop and so only the values that are bound to your variables after the last loop will be written to your csv. Indent it to be inside of the for-loop and every result will be written correctly to your csv-file. So your code will look like the following:

```py
class YellowPages(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yp'

    start_urls = [
           "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=agent&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=1",
           ]

    def parse(self, response):
        agent_name = response.xpath("//a[@class='business-name']/span/text()").extract()
        phone_number = response.xpath("//div[@class='phones phone primary']/text()").extract()
        address = response.xpath("//div[@class='street-address']/text()").extract()
        locality = response.xpath("//div[@class='locality']/text()").extract()


        data = zip(agent_name, phone_number, address, locality)

        for item in data:
            info = {
                'page' : response.url,
                'Agent_name': item[0],
                'Phone_number': item[1],
                'address': item[2],
                'locality': item[3],
            }
            yield info
```